# Please check that all tools that spawn Chromium are Arm-native

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm testing my code in my Mac. When I'm using chrome, the intellij reports this error, please help me! Thanks.

There are some other error information
`ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1022)] The use of Rosetta to run the x64 version of Chromium on Arm is neither tested nor maintained, and unexpected behavior will likely result. Please check that all tools that spawn Chromium are Arm-native.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'xuchichideMacBook-Air.local', ip: '2409:8734:1a70:7e2:40c6:c076:9d9b:fcf1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.3.1', java.version: '1.8.0_372'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver`

Comment: Have you got a chance to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: I should choose a property chromedriver version for chrome.You can check that in website.